# If else then execute another mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem: I want to use result of this query in if clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM user 
WHERE userid = 1234 AND password = 1234;
```

The concept is like this in my pseudocode - I don't know how to do it

```
if (count = 0) {
    SELECT logintattempt 
    INTO @temp 
    FROM user 
    WHERE userid = 1234

    SELECT (@temp+1) INTO @temp
}

SELECT loginattempt 
FROM user 
WHERE userid = 1234;

if(loginattempt >= 3) {
     UPDATE user 
     SET status = 'blocked' 
     WHERE userid = 1234;
}
```

If count 0 then login attempt will increase and when the login attempts is more than 3, it will be execute update status into blocked

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to know how to use the result from

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE userid=1234 AND password=1234;
```

into the if statement. Here's what you do:

```
SET @count:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE userid=1234 AND password=1234);
SELECT @count;
```

Does this help?

Comment: i want execute only in mysql not in another programming languange, thanks for helping

Comment: `SET @count:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE userid=1234 AND password=1234);
SELECT @count;

if (@count) {
SELECT logintattempt INTO @temp FROM user WHERE userid=1234
SELECT (@temp+1) INTO @temp
}

SELECT loginattempt FROM user where userid=1234;
if(loginattempt >= 3){
UPDATE user set status = 'blocked' where userid=1234;
}`

like this if i add the if clause?

Comment: i think you can use case expressions,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: make it  if(@count==0) and try. Then tell me what happens and we'll fix it.